# Istio - namespace-level access control is applied to only a single value in the list

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, rbac

I'm running Istio 1.2.3 in a GKE environment. I've set up the sock-shop demo-application, and am trying to configure HTTP authorization on namespace-level. I've enabled istio's RBAC, and am running the following Servicerole:

```
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ServiceRole
metadata:
  name: service-viewer
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - services: ["*"]
    methods: ["GET"]
    constraints:
    - key: "destination.labels[name]"
      values: ["front-end", "catalogue", "catalogue-db", "carts", "carts-db", "queue-master", "rabbitmq", "orders", "orders-db"]
```

and the following ServiceRoleBinding:

```
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ServiceRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: bind-service-viewer
  namespace: default
spec:
  subjects:
  - properties:
      source.namespace: "istio-system"
  - properties:
      source.namespace: "default"
  roleRef:
    kind: ServiceRole
    name: "service-viewer"
```

the sock-shop has been deployed in the `default` namespace, whereas istio, as usual, is deployed in the `istio-system` namespace.

However, when i connect to the website, only the front-end loads. The front-end is supposed to fetch the catalogue and carts pages. However, as seen in [kiali](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKx3Y.png), 100% of the traffic going from the front-end to catalogue and carts ends with a 5xx response code. If i remove istio's RBAC, [traffic flows succesfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykbaM.png).

Comment: Just curious, are you using the `istion on gke` add-on or did you install istio yourself manually?

Comment: Installed the latest version manually.

Comment: The role and rolebinding looks good to me. The only thing that comes to mind off the top of my head is the fact you are only allowing GET requests, can you verify that none of the pods use a different method?

Comment: As an alternative, could i replace the GET with a wildcard to see if that works?

Comment: yeah that would work too